# OutOfMemoryError Whilst Writing a String to a ByteArrayOutputStream

Tags: android, arrays, bytearrayoutputstream

I have a method which I have an array of String objects which I need to write to a ByteArrayOutputStream which later on I will write into a ZipOutputStream.

Here is my code.

```
// SAVE THE STRING AS A BYTE ARRAY IN MEMORY INSTEAD OF CREATING AND SAVING TO A NEW FILE
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            DataOutputStream byteOut = new DataOutputStream(baos);
            byte[] data;
            if (i == 1) {
                if (nodeStringArray != null) {
                    for (String s : nodeStringArray) {
                        byteOut.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                    }
                }
            } else {
                data = stringArray.get(i).getBytes("UTF-8");
                byteOut.write(data);
            }


            byteOut.close();
            byte[] input = baos.toByteArray();

            ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
            entry.setSize(input.length);
            zos.putNextEntry(entry);
            zos.write(input);
            zos.closeEntry();
```

The issue is, and I have only received on crash report for it, I am getting an `OutOfMemoryError` on the line that reads `byteOut.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));`

Anyone know of a better way of doing this or can see if I am doing something wrong?

**IDEA**

Could I put a try catch statement around the problem and when it happens call `byteOut.flush()`?

**Thanks in advance**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making to many copies of the data, and this is causing you to run out of memory.

You should be directly writing into your `ZipOutputStream` in your first loop.

```
ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry(fileName);
zos.putNextEntry(entry);
for (String s : nodeStringArray) {
    zos.write(s.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
zos.closeEntry();
```